# Problem with starting Word 2007 under Wine in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, microsoft-office, wine

I have installed word 2007 in Ubuntu Linux under Wine (The version is 1.2.2). And when i running word 2007 i have this error.

[image]

What's the problem?

There is a Wine configuration

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I was only able to run it when I told wine to use Windows XP api emulation, so try this.

Answer (score 1):

Curiously, WineHQ only reports on the [installer](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992), making no guarantees about the actual software. This, I would guess, is not the best omen for your efforts.

If you really want MS Office, you could probably try [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/), as I've heard it in a lot of discussions about running Office under Linux. (I would also suggest OO.org, but I'm guessing you are only running MSO because OO.org couldn't do what you needed).

Also, run it under `winedbg` - that will provide a little more insight into the source of the error.

Comment: It does report on Word itself - but under a seperate application (search for Word - then go through to the 2nd results page, and you can find it there)

Answer (score 0):

Under my current version of Linux Mint 15 using "Play on Linux-4.2.1" I was able to install and run Office 2007.

Comment: Can you offer a link or more information on that program? It will help the post much better

Comment: This reads as a comment, as it does not answer the question.